# Show or hide selectbox based on dropdown box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide or show selectbox based on first selectbox option. I'm not really sure why is it not working. Another thing is, how could i add multiple ID's in one section (if user select "project" or "mods" to show selectbox 2)?

Selectbox 1:

```
<select name="category_0" id="category_0" onchange="qa_category_select('category');" class="king-form-tall-select" style="display: none;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Projects</option>
    <option value="2">Mods</option>
</select>

<span id="category_0_sub">
<select name="category_1" id="category_1" onchange="qa_category_select('category');" class="king-form-tall-select">
<option value="" selected=""></option>
<option value="1">Projects</option>
<option value="2">Mods</option>
</select>
<span id="category_1_sub"> <select name="category_2" id="category_2" onchange="qa_category_select('category');" class="king-form-tall-select">
<option value="" selected=""></option>
<option value="124">3D Art</option>
<option value="125">Adventure</option>
</select>
</span></span>
```

Selectbox 2:

```
<select name="extra1" class="king-form-tall-select">
<option value="" selected=""></option>
<option value="value36">1.11</option>
<option value="value1">Older</option>
</select>
```

JS in HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category_1').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#extra1").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#extra1").hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

If anyone has idea on how to fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var possibleValues = [1, 2];
    $('#category_1').on('change', function() {
      $("#extra1").toggle(possibleValues.indexOf(+this.value) !== -1);
    });
});
</script>
```

where posibleValues is an array of all select values (in my case it is 1 and 2 for Projects and Mods accordingly) that should show the second select. So you don't need to add multiple id's to second select (also you can't do this, id is unique and single word)

Also, as @Satpal noticed you need to add ID "extra1" to second select

Comment: well, if your first select builds after script executing - it will not work. You can try to delegate event:
$(document).on('change', '#category_1', function() { .... })

and it will work dynamically

Comment: I didn't use your code i used my code as it's for some reason works if you change category_1 to category_0 (problem is it only hide box). Later i found out, if nothing is selected category is named "category_0" not "category_1". After you select something it use category_0 and category_1. But as category_1 is not pointed to anything it can't really show the "extra1" so now i'm not sure how to fix that.

Also i updated "Selectbox 1"